# trouble installing pygame on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, python, python3, pip

I had a hard time installing ***pygame*** on my **ubuntu 16.04 LTS**. I use **python 3**. these are the steps I took to install pygame:

1.first I installed `pip`:

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

this is the output of running `pip --version`:

```
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```

2. I executed the following commands:

`sudo apt-get install python3-dev mercurial`

`sudo apt-get install libsdl-image1.2-dev libsdl2-dev libsdl-ttf2.0-dev`

3. then I executed the following command:

`pip install --user hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame`

and this is the result in terminal:

```
Collecting hg+http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame
  Cloning hg http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame to /tmp/pip-req-build-hxy86__i
abort: error: Connection reset by peer
Command "hg clone --noupdate -q http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame /tmp/pip-req-build-hxy86__i" failed with error code 255 in None
```

and it fails to install pygame. what should I do??

Comment: From http://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame: *Moved to github. https://github.com/pygame/pygame/*. Also consider reading https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @Thomas so you mean that I should use `pip install --user hg+https://github.com/pygame/pygame` instead??

Comment: @Thomas it gives me the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install PyGame for Python 3.x on Ubuntu 16.04 (default python3 is version 3.5.1) open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-setuptools
sudo easy_install3 pip
python3 -m pip install --user pygame
```

The above commands also work on Ubuntu 18.04.

To install PyGame for Python 3.x on Ubuntu 19.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

To install PyGame for Python 3.x on Ubuntu 18.10 open the terminal and type:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add this line to sources.list.

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ cosmic-proposed universe
```

Save sources.list with the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Update the list of available software and install python3-pygame.

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install python3-pygame
```

---

To install PyGame for Python 2.x in Ubuntu 20.04 and earlier open the terminal and type:

```
 sudo apt install python-pygame
```