# trying to run a python game with source code in terminal, unbuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, python, games

not to get to complicated but I just wanted to run a simple tic tac toe program but couldn't find one that worked so i gravitated towards this after a duckduckgo search for python games, have no idea what i'm doing, any suggestion for a newbie would be great

https://github.com/xer0nex/a-python-game
I do not know what I am doing, can basically do "hello world" or "blastoff" and run it in the terminal. that's it
I logged into github and downloaded the zip file of asteroid in the link above.
placed it in the directory i wanted to run it in and got an error message trying to run the game in terminal.
the file downloaded was a folder called "a-python-game-master" and it downloaded to the desktop

```
cd Desktop
cd a-python-game-master
python3 Asteroid.py
```

the error message is below[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrxy1.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Asteroid.py", line 6, in <module>
    from Vex import Vex
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/a-python-game-master/Vex.py", line 3, in <module>
    import Environment
  File "/home/brian/Desktop/a-python-game-master/Environment.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [trouble installing pygame on ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058090/trouble-installing-pygame-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: @karel - I was just about to add this link to my answer; thank you for this! The github site for this game has absolutely no instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You've got (2) problems, neither is easily fixable. The module that your games are complaining about - **pygame** - is available for **python2** on Ubuntu 18 in package `python-pygame` (which won't work with these games). However, it *is* available for **python3** on Ubuntu 19 in package `python3-pygame` (which I assume works, but doesn't help you).

The source code for **pygame** is readily available, so if you're up to it, you could build it yourself.

FYI: the script you need to run is *MainGame.py*, not *Asteroids.py* (and it's super buggy).